# Is Node's Crypto module blocking even for methods that are not defined as sync

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could someone please give me some clarity if Node's Crypto module is blocking or not?  From what I thought I understood, some core modules can yield to a separate thread in c++.

I'm mainly interested in:

- crypto.createHmac
- crypto.createSign
- crypto.createVerify

If it does process on a separate thread, then fine.  If not, then I might have to think about using the cluster module.  I'm attempting to avoid blocking the main event loop.

Here is a trivial example of how I would implement crypto.createHmac.

```
function createHmac(algo, secret, data, callback) {
  var cryptoStream = crypto.createHmac(algo, secret);

  // Emitters
  cryptoStream
    .on('error', function (err) {
      return callback(err);
    });

  // Write the data
  cryptoStream.write(data, 'utf8', function(){
    cryptoStream.end();
    return callback(null, cryptoHmacStream.read());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "crypto.create*" functions you list are synchronous and blocking, however, they are quite trivial and just set up some basic data structures. They do not perform any heavy crypto computation, which happens later in asynchronous non-blocking methods. Thus, these are fine to call in the main event loop. They are no different than doing basic string manipulation, regex matching, etc in terms of overhead and do not require special treatment. You do not need the cluster module. Your snippet is already asynchronous and non-blocking because the `cryptoStream` is asynchronous by way of the event emitter pattern. The `write` method is asynchronous, which is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

To contradict the previous answer, as far as I understand, the `crypto.createHmac` method does all computation on the main thread in C++, but this is still the same thread as the event loop.

Your snippet is not actually asynchronous and not actually non-blocking. The interface only looks asynchronous. It will still use up time on your event loop.

For truly asynchronous crypto methods and better throughput, use [crypto-async](https://github.com/ronomon/crypto-async).